# Notificação no menu "conquistas" mostrando novo score que eu não ganhei

Tags: bug, status-pronto

**Atualização 18:48 GMT - 28/09/17**

Acabou de ocorrer:

[image: bug]

---

---

---

Sei que pareceu estranho, mas ontem e hoje apareceu +38 e hoje apareceu +46, ao clicar pra visualizar no menu e não aparece nada enquanto eu estava usando o site:

[image: score]

Em seguida o score novo some do menu, então fui no meu perfil e não houve mesmo nada, não houve nem mesmo reversão de votos seriais:

[image: alteração]

A alteração de score que esta na imagem já estava antes de aparecer as alterações estranhas.

---

### [edição: ~15:00]

Acabou de acontecer novamente:

[image: score]

mas quando abri o meu só mostrou isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a unica coisa que ganhei foi +15 e um +1 de uma resposta que negativei o qual já foi removida e meu score geral também não mudou atém desses +16.

---

### [edição: ~17:00]

Novamente (as "5 da tarde"):

[image: novamente]

Comment: Se alguém remove uma resposta para a qual você deu voto negativo, você recebe os pontos de volta e eles contam ali, eu acho. Acho que alterações de voto também contam.

Comment: @Renan postei uma imagem, só houve uma resposta que negativei que foi removida e recebi +1 e recebi +15 de uma resposta minha que foi aceita, no entanto a pouco ocorreu novamente, o menu me mostrou +61.

Comment: Vira e mexe essas notificações dão uma louca mesmo, vamos ver se temos alguma posição oficial.

Comment: @Maniero estou começando a suspeitar que seja um BUG mesmo, como o valor só aumentou então presumo que de alguma forma esta me sendo mostrado uma soma do score, mas não tenho como ter certeza :/

Comment: Aconteceu comigo também(40 numa resposta quando deveria ser 25), no entanto, numa visualização posterior já apresentou correcto.

Comment: @ramaral estou começando a pensar que é algo com o "cache back-end" e as mudanças do menu que ocorreram nos ultimos dias.